# AngularJS http GET throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm writing a custom error object and testing it with "no connection".

Here the stacktrace:

```
(anonymous function)    @   angular-1.4.7.js:12477
               error    @   httpService.js:34
        processQueue    @   angular-1.4.7.js:14745
(anonymous function)    @   angular-1.4.7.js:14761
         Scope.$eval    @   angular-1.4.7.js:15989
       Scope.$digest    @   angular-1.4.7.js:15800
        Scope.$apply    @   angular-1.4.7.js:16097
                done    @   angular-1.4.7.js:10546
     completeRequest    @   angular-1.4.7.js:10744
        requestError    @   angular-1.4.7.js:10695
```

I'm just calling a simple `$http.get(url)` and 2 callback `function`s.
In the error callback I want to log the error in my custom object which contains the url, error, ... .

Is there a way to fix it?

### Update

```
this.get = function (url) {
    var call = new HttpCall(url); // my custom class
    // $log.debug(url);
    $http.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            call.response = response;
            $log.info(call);
            return response
        }, function (error) {
            call.error = error;
            $log.error(error);
            $log.error(call);
            return error;
        });
};
```

Comment: please share your httpService.js file

Comment: You probably want to create an Interceptor for your purposes, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http